# Styling JQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dmsrY/28/)

I'm trying to style the sections inside the AutoComplete, but I don't know what to put in the CSS *for* the sections. I'm specifically trying to make:

```
color: #96f226;
border-radius: 0px;
border: 1px solid #454545;
```

Any suggestions???

Comment: What do you mean? You're not sure which CSS selector to use?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Are you looking for this selector?:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    background:red;
    height:10px;
    font-size:8px;
}
```

Ugly demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/zeSTc/

Just replace with your code:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a{
    color: #96f226;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #454545;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w5Dt2/

Comment: **Yes!!!** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dmsrY/30/) is the finished program I have been asking most of my questions on. *THANKS!*

Comment: for jquery-ui 1.12.1 Try : 
`.ui-menu-item div.ui-state-active{//your styling here}`

Comment: Hi the second link is broken.

Answer (score 79):

Bootstrap styling for jQuery UI Autocomplete

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;   
    padding: 4px 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #ccc;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;
}

.ui-menu-item > a.ui-corner-all {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #555555;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.ui-state-hover, .ui-state-active {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #0088cc;
    border-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: When using this with an input-field in the navbar, the width is initially wider than the searchbox. Setting "top: 0" solved this for me.

Comment: it's exactly like I wanted!

Comment: Unless you don't mind a list that extends forever, i would throw a `max-height: 50vh` and an `overflow-y: auto` on there

Comment: Note, this is not limited to use with bootstrap.  It uses the jQuery & jQuery3 classes

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to assign an html id to that list so that you can style multiple lists differently if on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @md-nazrul-islam reply, This is what I did with SCSS:

```
ul.ui-autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    display: none;
    min-width: 160px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    //@include border-radius(5px);
    @include box-shadow( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0 5px 10px );
    @include background-clip(padding-box);
    *border-right-width: 2px;
    *border-bottom-width: 2px;

    li.ui-menu-item{
        padding:0 .5em;
        line-height:2em;
        font-size:.8em;
        &.ui-state-focus{
            background: #F7F7F7;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can overwrite the classes in your own css using !important, e.g. if you want to get rid of the rounded corners.

```
.ui-corner-all
{
border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Two remarks: You don't need to set a unit after `0`. `0` is always 0. Second, setting !important isn't seen as good coding style. You'll probably run into a cascade where !important is unintendendly overwriting your styles later on.