# Change style of only one auto complete on site

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, autocomplete

Using this Q `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17838380/styling-jquery-ui-autocomplete`

I was able to style all auto completes on my site. However I only want to apply WIDTH style to one particular auto-complete text field.

```
        <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableCountries = [   
 "Country1",
    "Country2",
    "Country3",
    ];
    $("#tbCountries").autocomplete({
      source: availableCountries
    });
  } );
  </script>



<input id="tbCountries" type="text" class="textEntry form-control RegistrationPage-AutoCompleteCountryWidth" maxlength="30">
```

Ive tried accessing it through the ID of the input and also adding a class

```
#tbCountries ul
{
     width:14% !important;
}

.RegistrationPage-AutoCompleteCountryWidth ul
{
   width:14% !important;
}
```

None of these work....BUT...by getting the ID of the ul from the developer tools I can change the desired width to

```
#ui-id-1
{
    width:14% !important; WORKING
}
```

However, isnt this bad coding so to speak as adding or removing more auto completes from my site could change the id of this one?

Any Ideas?
Ta

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("yourclass")[0].style.width="14% !important";

Answer (score 0):

You try to select an `ul` element as a child of the input.
In CSS you select children of an element with spaces between the selectors.

Try this instead (just the ID without `ul` childselector):

```
#tbCountries {
     width:14% !important;
}
```

For further reading: 
https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/