# How to inspect an auto-complete widget with chrome's inspector?

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete, chrome-debugging

I am trying to use [jquery-ui's autocomplete widget](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) (1.12) and it looks weird.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47351103) that has some advice about style, version unknown.

Normally I would open the page in chrome, open the debugger, click on the button that says "Select an element in the page to inspect it (flower up-arrow C)", then click on the element to inspect, and I'd see all the styles.

However, when I click on the debugger select, the autocomplete goes away.  If I type so the autocomplete comes up, the debugger select goes away.  Same behavior with the keyboard shortcuts.

How do you inspect the styles of an jquery-ui autocomplete result window in chrome?

*EDIT*: I never was able to inspect, but I did get `.ui-menu` and `.ui-menu-item` to work, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17838585).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17293612/14518353

Comment: I don't think so? Not sure how to console log the style on an autocomplete box, especially when it will disappear when I start typing in the console.

Comment: I dont mean console.log(), but I thought you were looking to find the source code of the extension. If so, that's where it would be

Answer (score 0):

You can just search the for **ui-widget** or **ui-autocomplete** in the Elements Tab of the dev tools. You should be able to find a  - remove the "display: none" - this should do it.

[image: Should look something like this]

Comment: Oh interesting. I can search for `ui-` in the Elements tab, and I see the style, which is helpful. I cannot modify it, though. It's in a text window, and when I double-click on it, nothing happens. Thoughts?